# Replace path name to get value using received JSON response key javascript

Tags: javascript, json, function, methods, postman

Given json response below.

```
    {
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
    "cheapest": {
        "data": [
      {
        "logistic_id": 1,
        "rate_id": 21
      }
    ]
    },
    "reguler": {
        "data":[
      {
        "logistic_id": 5,
        "rate_id": 74
      }
    ]
    },
    "ranked": {
        "data": []
    }
}
}
```

to get logistic_id value and store to logisticIdValue, I use path:

```
set("logisticIdValue", x.data.reguler.data[0].logistic_id)
```

I want to get logistic_id value from response using iteration so i don't have to write const cheapest, reguler and ranked to iterate. It might involve `key` syntax, something like this but i don't know whats the proper syntax to do this

```
set("logisticIdValue", x.data.key[1].data[0].logistic_id)
```

Comment: Do you have function callled set? Do you want to get List of all logistic_id so expected result [1,5]?

Comment: I want to get logistic_id value by simpler way
set("logisticIdValue", x.data.reguler.data[0].logistic_id) syntax. I mind this will be:
set("logisticIdValue", x.data.cheapest.data[0].logistic_id)
set("logisticIdValue", x.data.reguler.data[0].logistic_id)
set("logisticIdValue", x.data.ranked.data[0].logistic_id)
i want to get those value by iterating property 'cheapest', 'reguler', ranked'

Answer (score 0):

```js
let data = {
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "cheapest": {
      "data": [{
        "logistic_id": 1,
        "rate_id": 21
      }]
    },
    "reguler": {
      "data": [{
        "logistic_id": 5,
        "rate_id": 74
      }]
    },
    "ranked": {
      "data": []
    }
  }
};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
  if (key === 'data') {
    for (const [key1, value1] of Object.entries(value)) {
      for (const [key2, value2] of Object.entries(value1)) {
        value2 && value2.map((e, i, arr) => {
          console.log('logistic_id:', e.logistic_id);
        })
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to get array of logistic_id values for all types `(cheapest,reguler, ..)`

so you can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function to iterate on [`Object.Keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and accumulate it into array as the following:

```js
const data = {
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "cheapest": {
            "data": [
                {
                    "logistic_id": 1,
                    "rate_id": 21
                }
            ]
        },
        "reguler": {
            "data": [
                {
                    "logistic_id": 5,
                    "rate_id": 74
                }
            ]
        },
        "ranked": {
            "data": []
        }
    }
};

const logisticIdValues = Object.keys(data.data).reduce((result, key) => {
    if (data.data[key].data.length > 0) {
         result.push(data.data[key].data[0].logistic_id);
    }
    return result;
}, []);

console.log(logisticIdValues)
```

but if you need to get it attached to its type so you can accumulated it in hash instead of array as the following:

```js
const data = {
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "cheapest": {
            "data": [
                {
                    "logistic_id": 1,
                    "rate_id": 21
                }
            ]
        },
        "reguler": {
            "data": [
                {
                    "logistic_id": 5,
                    "rate_id": 74
                }
            ]
        },
        "ranked": {
            "data": []
        }
    }
};


const logisticIdValuesObj = Object.keys(data.data).reduce((result, key) => {
    if (data.data[key].data.length > 0) {
         result[key] = data.data[key].data[0].logistic_id;
    }
    return result;
}, {});

console.log(logisticIdValuesObj)
```